# how to make a variable to a json work like a link in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a variable in a .json link

for example

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/102376e7c0e1c995/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json
```

this is a `JSON` that give a weather data for example I want to give to my  website visitor his  weather condition I want to make variable to this `JSON` link in country and city

for example

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/102376e7c0e1c995/geolookup/conditions/q/"country variable here "/"city variable here".json
```

Comment: I assume you are looking for string concatenation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators

Comment: If not, please explain your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var state = 'CA';
var city = 'San_Francisco';
var URL = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/102376e7c0e1c995/geolookup/conditions/q/' + state + '/' + city + '.json';

$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(parsed_json) {
        var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
        var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
        alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
    }
});​
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jMY3Z/)